# cUrl: Undefined reference

Tags: c++, windows, curl, codeblocks

I am trying to use cUrl in my app but i am getting several errors. I already tried to find a solution on g or here, but nothing helped. 
I build and link cUrl as static, have libcurl.a set up in linker, have proper includes but it still doesn't work.

I tried adding -lcurl into build settings but seems like it doesn't know that flag.

I am using cUrl 7.46.0 build with --disable--static and --without--ssl
 and Code::Blocks ide & mingw compiler // c++ ofc

Here are those errors:

```
obj\Release\src\HTTPDownloadRequest.o:HTTPDownloadRequest.cpp| undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
obj\Release\src\HTTPDownloadRequest.o:HTTPDownloadRequest.cpp| undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
obj\Release\src\HTTPDownloadRequest.o:HTTPDownloadRequest.cpp| undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
obj\Release\src\HTTPDownloadRequest.o:HTTPDownloadRequest.cpp| undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
obj\Release\src\HTTPDownloadRequest.o:HTTPDownloadRequest.cpp| undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
```

Compilation command:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\WXWID\lib\gcc_lib -o bin\Release\app.exe obj\Release\app.o obj\Release\appMain.o obj\Release\appHistory.o obj\Release\src\HTTPDownloadRequest.o  obj\Release\resource.res -s -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static -mthreads  -lwxmsw30u_core -lwxbase30u -lwxpng -lwxjpeg -lwxtiff -lwxzlib C:\WXWID\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw30u_adv.a "C:\curl\lib\libcurl.a" -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomctl32 -lwsock32 -lodbc32 -mwindows
```

Errors when used define CURL_STATICLIB

```
C:\curl\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-connect.o)| undefined reference to `WSAIoctl@36'
C:\curl\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-ldap.o)| undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_err2stringA'
C:\curl\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-ldap.o)| undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_msgfree'
C:\curl\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-ldap.o)|| undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_unbind_s'
...
```

Comment: Can you post the full compilation phrase? (g++ -lcurl ....) Did you specify the path to the link libraries with -L ?

Comment: @jensa Well, it's up ... seems strange tho. I added it the same way I did wxWidgets and they're working fine, strange it doesn't. Did I messed something up ?

Comment: What's "C:\curl\lib\libcurl.a" ? Why don't you do -lcurl ? Add -LC:\curl\lib and -lcurl

Comment: @jensa I did it manually but still the same problem :/ Only this time it doesn't throw error on -lcurl flag ...

Comment: Well, you're doing something wrong. Did you put the -LC:\curl\lib before -lcurl ?

Comment: @jensa Seems like, and yes. Can it be 'cause of bad build of curl ?

Comment: `WSAIoctrl` is in `Ws2_32.lib` and ldap functions are in `Wldap32.lib`

Comment: @jensa & frymode Hell god, I got it working. Without you two i wouldnt stand a chance. Thanks so much ! It was bothering me whole month, thanks !

Comment: Glad to hear you got it to work! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to link with static libcurl add `-DCURL_STATICLIB` to gcc arguments or define `CURL_STATICLIB` macro before including its headers to use correct mangling.

Comment: Just tried both of them. 
Define creates more errors than before, but with argument it makes those same 5 errors.

Comment: check again, at least `_imp_` prefix in expected symbol name should disappear

Comment: Also command you showed is only linking of already compiled cpp files. You should recompile with given macro definition.

Answer (score -1):

I would do

```
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\curl\lib -lcurl ................
```